# Adicionar titulo ao lado de sua imagem correspondente

Tags: html, css, html-tags

Estou aprendendo ***HTML*** e ***CSS*** e estou fazendo um site para praticar e to com uma duvida.

Quero colocar o titulo das imagens uma do lado da outra.

"Os melhores Cookie's" do lado **direito** da imagem correspondente.

"O melhore café" do lado **esquerdo** da sua imagem correspondente.

Consegui colocar o primeiro texto no lugar certo, porem ao adicionar o outro simplemente não consigo colocar do lado esquerdo da segunda imagem.

[image]

HTML abaixo:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="logo.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="title1">
            <h1> Os melhores Cookie's!</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="title2">
            <h1> O melhor Café!</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="foto1">
            <img src="cookie.jpg">
        </div>


        <div id="foto2">
            <img src="cafe.jpg">
        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS ABAIXO

```
#container{
    width: 1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#foto1{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

#foto1 img{
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-top: 250px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

#foto2{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

#foto2 img{
    margin-left: 450px;
    padding-top: 150px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#title1 {
    text-align:center;
    width: 370px;
    max-height: 45px;
    background-color: tan;
    border-radius: 10px 20px;
    font-family: Comic Sans MS;
    margin-top: 265px;
    float: right;
}


#title2 {
    text-align:center;
    width: 370px;
    max-height: 45px;
    background-color: tan;
    border-radius: 10px 20px;
    font-family: Comic Sans MS;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara a forma como vc montou seu HTML não está muito legal... A minha sugestão é colocar cada par Imagem+Titulo dentro de um container, e usar flex para alinha-los.

Veja esse exemplo

```css
.title{
    text-align:center;
    background-color: tan;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: Comic Sans MS;
}

.box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="https://placecage.com/50/50">
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="container">

    <div class="box">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
        <h1 class="title">Os melhores Cookie's!</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <h1 class="title">O melhor Café!</h1>
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pseudo selectors ao inves de usar H1.

:before
e
:after

Exemplo:

```
.classedaimagem1:before {
float: right;
content: "seu texto";
}
.classedaimagem2:before {
float: left;
content: "seu texto";
}
```

caso necessário, para melhor posicionamento e formatação de cores, tamanhos, etc. use parâmetros:
Padding, margin, Top, left, right, etc.

Veja o código fonte
deste link -> https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/PseudoElementsImageCaptions/

Comment: Só uma observação, quando vc usa o texto como content vc não consegui seleciona-lo com o mouse...

Comment: Mas pelo que entendi no código dele, ele quer atribuir LINK, e isso consegue tanto com HTML5 quando com Javascript Ou Jquery.